# Foreign currency processing

Tags: currency

We are looking to expand our e-commerce store to allow customers in countries outside of the United States to shop and see prices specific to their region.  The prices are not just straight markups from the US prices;  we build the cost to ship the product, any tariffs / export fees, etc.

We are looking to keep our payment processor that only processes US dollars.  It all integrates back into our Navision database and we didn't want to do multi-currency in our backend systems.  Our plan was to do a currency conversion at the time of sale (say, $300 Canadian dollars would mean we would authorize the customer's credit card for $231.94 USD).

The problem comes when the actual posting takes place, they might pay a little more or less depending on the currency rate at the given time (usually a few days after the sale has been authorized).

Have others worked around this problem by stating on their checkout page that the actual amount may fluctuate based on currency conversion?  Or does everyone just find a payment processor to charge in the foreign currency?  Or do customers generally not care if they see a little more or less on their statements?

Comment: I think this is actually a business decision. Whether or not you have revenue in multiple currencies has implications far beyond the technical details of payment processing.

Comment: Did you ask your company lawyer first?

Comment: You should show the currency conversion to the user (show them the final amount in USD) and have them agree to it. You generally can't charge someone something that they haven't agreed to. Moreover by listing products in the local currency, you are probably going to be held to the consumer protection laws of that jurisdiction, which may restrict what you can put into any click-through agreement. Make sure your company lawyer understands the jurisdictions that you want to sell in.

Comment: You should also check how much will be coming out of the customer's account due to fees. If I see a webpage charging €299.99 for a product, I don't care how you handle it, but I expect no more than €299.99 to leave my bank account. On the other hand, if I use my card in the USA and pay $US with my European card, then I expect that there will be bank charges and take that into account in my buying decision.

Comment: Yeah, our plan is to show the amount in the customer's currency, and then below it show the current rate and what we are going to charge their account in USD.  We are also putting a statement on there about currency fluctuations and that their issuing card may charge them a foreign currency convenience fee.  But I mostly wanted to hear what others have been doing.